# Creating a quadratic formula solver - variables not declared in scope

Tags: c++

So i've been working on this assignment which is to create a quadratic formula solver in C++ and for the most part I believe i've got everything but I keep receiving errors:

main.cpp:54:11: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope

But I receive this error for every variable in equSolver() and outResults()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void findCoeff();
void equSolver(double a, double b, double c, double d);
double discr(double a, double b, double c);
void outResults(double root1, double root2, double a, double b, double c, double d);

void findCoeff(){
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;

        cout << "\nEnter coefficient a:\n";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "\nEnter coefficient b:\n";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "\nEnter coefficient c:\n";
        cin >> c;
}

double discr(double a, double b, double c){

    double d;
    d = pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);
    return d;
}

void equSolver(double a, double b, double c, double d){
    double root1 = ((-1 * b) + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    double root2 = ((-1 * b) - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);

}

void outResults(double root1, double root2, double a, double b, double c, double d){
    if( std::isnan(root1) || std::isnan(root2)){
        cout << "Quadratic equation with the following coefficients: \n";
        cout << "a: " << a << "; b: " << b << "; c: " << c << "\n";
        cout << "has no roots in the real domain\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Quadratic equation with the following coefficients: \n";
        cout << "a: " << a << "; b:" << b << "; c:" << "\n";
        cout << "has the following roots\n";
        cout << "Root1: " << root1 << "; Root2: " << root2 << "\n";

    }
}

int main(){
findCoeff();
equSolver(a, b, c, d);
outResults(root1, root2, a, b, c, d);
}
```

I've tried to delcare the variables within main or as the parameters but then they all just stay as 0. The program runs but no calculations are actually done.

Thanks

Comment: What `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` do you expect to use in `main` when you do `equSolver(a, b, c, d);`?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Which part of it are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: The input from findCoeff().
I can get the program to compile and run but when I do none of the variables are being used.
http://imgur.com/uI6DExF

Comment: You need to read textbook about variables, their lifetime etc, you do not understand basic concepts

Comment: ***The input from findCoeff()*** You throw it away. Remember that the local variables defined in a `findCoeff()` do not exist after `findCoeff()` finishes. They also have no ties at all to variables of the same name located somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Please read about scope of variables. In fact why not read a book on C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue understanding how variables are used in C++. For example your function

```
void findCoeff();
```

creates three local `double` variables, enters values into them from `std::cin` and then discards them. For some reason you think that they would magically appear in `main()` which calls that function, but that is not the case. Same for `equSolver()` - you calculate 2 values, store them in 2 variables and then discard. Later you expect them to magically appear inside `main()` and to be passed to the next function. That does not work this way in C++. You have to define those variables in `main()` and then somehow make functions to store values into them. For example you can use references:

```
void findCoeff( double &ra, double &rb, double &rc ){
    cout << "\nEnter coefficient a:\n";
    cin >> ra;
    cout << "\nEnter coefficient b:\n";
    cin >> rb;
    cout << "\nEnter coefficient c:\n";
    cin >> rc;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    findCoeff( a, b, c ); // now findCoeff() would modify a,b, and c through reference and you can use that values
    double d = discr(a, b, c);
    ...
}
```

better way would be for that function to return that values (like `discr()` does), but due to complications of returning multiple values that topic is too advanced for you at the moment.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much!
That makes a whole lot more sense now.
So if I define a variable in main and in the parameters of a function, do I also need to declare it within the function?

Comment: @Mathium np, pay attention, I renamed references names, I think that should let you anderstand that names of them and names of variables in `main()` are unrelated

Comment: @Mathium If you declare local variable within function that variable leaves only until this function terminates. In your case no, you do not need to create them. You should understand that local variable `a` inside `main()` is not the same as local variable `a` within `findCoeff()`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `main()` function:

```
int main(){
    findCoeff();
    equSolver(a, b, c, d);
    outResults(root1, root2, a, b, c, d);
}
```

Your program starts by entering `main()` and calls `findCoeff()`.

```
void findCoeff(){
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;

        cout << "\nEnter coefficient a:\n";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "\nEnter coefficient b:\n";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "\nEnter coefficient c:\n";
        cin >> c;
}
```

Here, `a`, `b`, and `c` are in **local scope** because they are inside a function. Only `findCoeff()` can see them. After the user enters the values for `a`, `b`, and `c` and `findCoeff()` exits, these local scope variables will be discarded.

So let's return to `main()`:

```
int main(){
    findCoeff();
    equSolver(a, b, c, d);
    outResults(root1, root2, a, b, c, d);
}
```

Now you're asking for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, none of which have been declared within `main()`. This is why you get: `main.cpp:54:11: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope`

If you want `a`, `b`, `c` (and `d`) to be visible back in `main()`, one solution is to put them in **global scope** i.e. outside of a function.

```
double a;
double b;
double c;
double d;
void findCoeff(){
        cout << "\nEnter coefficient a:\n";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "\nEnter coefficient b:\n";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "\nEnter coefficient c:\n";
        cin >> c;
}
...
```

Keep in mind that having global variables is bad practice. The better solution is given by Slava's answer, which avoids global variables. But if those concepts are beyond you at the moment, this should suffice for your assignment.